# nginx client_body_temp_path level

Tags: nginx, subdirectory

I have my `nginx` config as:

```
location  /file_upload {
    ...

    proxy_set_body              off; # do not forward request body
    client_body_in_file_only    on;  # store request body in file

    client_body_temp_path /some_path/tmp 1 2;
```

so, the dir `/some_path/tmp` will have many sub-directory like

`/some_path/tmp/1`, 
`/some_path/tmp/1/00`,
`/some_path/tmp/1/01`....

```
> ls /some_path/tmp/0
  01  03  05  07  09  11  13  15  17  19  21  23  25  27  29  31 ...
> ls /some_path/tmp/0/01
  00  02  04  06  08  10  12  14  16  18  20  22  24  26  28  30 ...
```

My question is: Will `Nginx` remove those sub-directory it self 
or `Nginx` will reuse those directory when comes to the max directory count?